# Computer won’t boot directly from new SSD

Tags: boot, grub

I got a new SSD and installed [Elementary OS Luna](http://elementaryos.org) onto it. But I can’t boot directly from this drive. I always have to select that I want to boot from the old HDD and than select in Grub, that I want to boot Elementary OS.

It works this way, but I want to be independent od the HDD and be able to boot directly from the SSD. The ideal scenario—if I have the SSD as primary drive for boot—I turn on the computer and it boots Elementary OS Luna without any questions. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Enter BIOS (while booting your PC, press either F1/F2/DEL/ESC, or whichever button opens BIOS on your system). Now search for something similar to "Boot Menu" and select it. Now select the SSD as primary boot device.